# I/O Board accepts "5V TTL, open/closed circuit" - So it will accept the closing of a circuit with no voltage?

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, communication

A digital I/O board has the following pins:

- Digital In Pin 1
- Digital In Pin 2
- Signal Ground
- Digital Out Pin 1
- Digital Out Pin 2

I am interested on how inputs into this board can be made. Its spec sheet says that it accepts "5V TTL, open/closed circuit". The spec sheet can be found here: [Link](https://cdn.cytivalifesciences.com/dmm3bwsv3/AssetStream.aspx?mediaformatid=10061&destinationid=10016&assetid=16302). There is no additional information.

I understand the 5V TTL part, if I have a sensor with a logical Output Pin, I could connect it to the I/O board this way:

- **Sensor** Output Pin <---> **Board** Digital In Pin 1
- **Sensor** Ground <---> **Board** Signal Ground

I do not understand the "open/closed circuit" part. Does this means that if I connect the Digitial In Pin 1 to the signal ground, it will read a 1? It would look like this:

- **Board** Digital In Pin 1 <--> **Board** Signal Ground

If so, how does the board monitor both cases? The voltage can be monitored by an internal voltimeter. The Open/closed by a resistance measurement circuit? And when the circuit is closed, resistance should be very low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a somewhat more informative section in the [Äkta Avant User Manual.](https://b3p.it.helsinki.fi/download/%C3%84kta_Avant_Manuals/%C3%84ktaAvant_User_Manual.pdf)  Your E9 module is an accessory for the Avant.

From page 147:

[image]

If you leave a digital input unconnected, it will read as a digital high (logical level 1.)  You have to intentionally pull it to ground to make it read a digital low (logical level 0.)

Answer (score 1):

Detection of a passive external switch must have internal pullup selected, added or automatically included by design in the datasheet specifications.

**Make no assumptions if uncertain!

Measure Voc open circuit input voltage and Isc current to 0V.**
Also, check for ESD protection.

### added

You did not include the detail "Closed Circuit = 0" in your question, which explicitly answers your question and implies a pullup is included.  Measuring the open circuit voltage will confirm this.  The resistance for this likely be >= 10k <= 1M.pullup. If this matters to you, you can test that.  A TTL **threshold** implies that will be around 1.3 to 1.5V as in 74HCT' logic

Comment: The datasheet is very sparse (I included it in the OP) and it does not contain information about ESD protection. How can I test it, or if needed, add it?

Comment: While not stated, it's possible that the input is optically isolated, in which case the effective pullup value will be rather less than you suggest.

Comment: Maybe , but "All connected equipment must have a common ground."  loses the CMRR if you have isolated Opto inputs from multiple independent sources sharing different grounds.   So unless stated "isolated inputs" I assume common TTL thresholds and 5V CMOS interface for digital signals meaning it can be driven with TTL or CMOS but the input is CMOS.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The digital input 9-pin pinout.*

You don't have to worry here. Your only option is to connect any of the digital inputs to signal ground. This can be done with a mechanical switch, an NPN transistor or a 5 V logic signal. You can assume that there is an internal pull-up resistor to keep the line high if unconnected.

> I do not understand the "open/closed circuit" part. Does this means that if I connect the Digitial In Pin 1 to the signal ground, it will read a 1?

It could work either way. The simplest way to be sure is to test it while monitoring on your PC.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if I connect a digital input pin to a *different* signal ground and not the one in the board itself?

Comment: You need to connect the grounds of both systems together. Otherwise there is no return path for the signal current. Otherwise it would be like connecting a wire to the top of a battery and expecting current to flow when there is no connection to the bottom of the battery.